# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" while using Python's equivalent of && (logical-and) in an while-statement

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
def subir_norte(altitudes,inicio):
     a3=altitudes[inicio[0]][inicio[1]]
     a4=altitudes[j][inicio[1]]
     p=[a,inicio[1]]
     for j in range(inicio[0]-1,-1,-1):
         while a4 < a3:
             a=j+1
         elif ((a4 >= a3) and j=0):
             a=0
         else subir_norte(altitudes,inicio)
      return p
```

when I try to run the program it gives me 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the 7th line.
how can I fix it?

Comment: `while` doesn't take an `elif` clause, only an `else` clause (which isn't simply used when the condition becomes false, and requires a semicolon).  What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: altitudes is a matrix, where which cell is an altitude,  and inicio is a cell from altitudes. From the cell indicated at  inicio, which is a tuple with the line and column, the code returns a tulip
with the coordinates of the cell reached in a rise to the north (decreasing the line) until the neighboring cell to the North does not have a higher altitude or has reached the limit of
matrix. @chepner

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
elif ((a4 >= a3) and j=0):
```

The `j=0` should have a double equals as in python equality is written using two equals so it should be

```
elif ((a4 >= a3) and j==0):
```

on another note the brackets are not neccesary (but don't change anything) so you could write it as

```
elif a4 >= a3 and j == 0:
```

Another issue is that this elif is part of a while loop so it should either be part of and if statement or an if statement itself.

Comment: It tried your correction and it is giving me same error. do you know anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: @Mpc could you add the full error traceback to the question?